# Find background shortcuts on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I'm having problem using one of the shortcuts in VS Code `ctrl + shift + L` but it works from selection menu.

I have noticed there is a loading circle above cursor when I press that shortcut (even in other apps) and I assumed maybe it's a different shortcut for windows which overrides it.

is there any app that would show me what is triggered when I use shortcuts in windows 10?

VS code developer shortcut troubleshooting doesn't recognize any shortcut but it does for `ctrl + shift + S`(workbench.action.files.saveAs) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMD Radeon software was interfering with the shortcut on the background.
disabled it on "hotkeys" section.
It didn't solve every shortcut malfunction, it resolved after I updated the graphic driver.

Comment: Mark this as the answer since you asked the question.

Comment: It needs 2 days interval